# Convert mixed list of Numpy arrays and Python lists to only Python lists

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list, `d2_sum`, that contains numpy arrays and python lists, and I'm trying to convert all to python lists so I can perform some slicing operations. I have,

`d2_sum_list = [i.tolist() if type(i) == 'numpy.ndarray' else i for i in d2_sum]`

This executes with no errors but does not convert any of the numpy arrays to python lists. What am I missing here?

Comment: you need to remove the quotes around numpy.ndarray, since it's a class and not a string

Comment: @asdf101 Thanks, now I feel stupid haha

Comment: np, happy to help

Comment: Or just `[list(x) for x in d2_sum]`. Sure, you needlessly re-create some lists, but it probably has a negligible impact on performance and keeps the code cleaner.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: `list(x)` doesn't do the same thing as `x.tolist()`. `tolist()` on a 2D array will produce a list of lists, while `list(x)` will produce a list of arrays. Also, `tolist()` produces ordinary Python scalars rather than NumPy scalars.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica ah, very good point.

Answer (score 1):

remove the quotes, because type(something) == "numpy.ndarray" will always be False:

```py
d2_sum_list = [i.tolist() if type(i) is numpy.ndarray else i for i in d2_sum]
```

Comment: More idiomatically, you'd use `type(i) is numpy.ndarray`, or `isinstance(i, numpy.ndarray)`, although those are not exactly the same (although effectively the same here)

Comment: very good point actually, I tend to forget `is` exists unless I check for None